# how to resolve Non-Static method cannot be referenced from a static context?

Tags: java, non-static

```
class Base {

    Base show() {
        System.out.println("Base");
        return new Base();
    }

    class Child4 extends Base {

        Child4 show() {
            System.out.println("Child4");
            return new Child4();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String... s) {
        Child4 C1 = new Child4();
        C1.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Disha. Welcome to stack overflow. Please make it easier to understand your question: What do you try with the code you posted? Do you get an error message, or does the code behave differently than you think it should? What do you think it should do, and what behavior did you observe?

Comment: Don't nest the Child4 class into the Base class. Use 2 different files: one for each class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)

Answer (score 2):

In your sample, `Child4` is a non static inner class of class `Base` (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) for documentation on inner classes). This means you need an instance of class `Base` in order to instantiate an object of class `Child4`.

Since in you example there is no access from the `Child4` instance to the outer `Base` instance, it seems the use of a non static inner class is not intended. You should declare this inner class static, with

```
static class Child4 extends Base {
```

This way, the call to `new Child4` will be legit from `main` static context.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

`public static void main(String... s) {  Base base= new Base(); Base.Child4 C1 = base.newChild4(); C1.show(); }`